# Installation error sql management studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ssms

I have visual studio 2013 ultimate and windows 8.1 . I tried to install SQL Management Studio 2012 and the error occurs

The following error has occurred:

Could not write value  to key \SOFTWARE.   Verify that you have sufficient access to that key, or contact your support personnel.

[image]

Need help to solve this.

Comment: Did you run the install as Administrator?

Comment: same error occurs when try to run with administrator